# This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

I keep getting the error This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405

I created a signup form. but when I submit, it doesn't show the action page.

**In html:
**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student Signup Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="\assets\css\main.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="flex-container">
  <div class="one"><a href="\index.html"><img src="\assets\images\vanierlogo.jpg" alt="logo"></a></div>
  <div class="two"><a href=\signup.html>Signup</a></div>
  <div class="three"><a href="\login.html">Login</a></div>
</nav>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<form> 
  <h3>Create New Student Account</h3><br><br>

  <label for="username">Student ID: </label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br><br>
  <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
  <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br><br>
  <label>Enter Password<sup>*</sup>: </label>
  <input type="password" autocomplete="passwd" name="passwd" required><br><br>
  <label>Confirm Password: </label>
  <input type="password" autocomplete="passwd1" name="passwd1" required><br><br>
  <label>Are you Full-Time or Part-Time?</label><br><br>
  <label for="Full-Time">Full-Time</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Full-Time" name="status" value="Full-Time">
  <label for="Part-Time">Part-Time</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Part-Time" name="status" value="Part-Time"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="createAccount(this)" value="Sign Up!"><br><br>
  <footer>* Password must be at least 3 characters in length</footer>
</form>
<script src="\assets\js\main.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

In main.js:

```
function createAccount(element) {
    const currForm = element.closest('form');

    const params = "username="+currForm.elements[0].value +
                  "&firstName="+currForm.elements[1].value + 
                  "&lastName="+currForm.elements[2].value + 
                  "&passwd="+currForm.elements[3].value + 
                  "&passwd1="+currForm.elements[4].value + 
                  "&status="+currForm.elements[5].value;
 
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:80/SignupHandlingServlet",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
    xhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert("DONE");
            alert(xhttp.status);
            if (xhttp.status==409 || xhttp.status==417 || xhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
            else {
                alert(xhttp.method);
            let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            document.querySelector("#ipText").innerHTML = response.ip;
            }
        }
        else if (xhttp.readyState==0) {
            alert("request unsent");
        } else if (xhttp.readyState==1){
            alert("request OPENED");
        } else if(xhttp.readyState==2) {
            alert("request HEADERS_RECEIVED");
        } else {
            alert("The HTTP request response is being downloaded");
        }
    }
}
```

**In web.xml:
**

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SignupHandlingServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>SignupHandlingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SignupHandlingServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SignupHandlingServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**In java:
**

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;

@WebServlet("/SignupHandlingServlet")
public class SignupHandlingServlet extends HttpServlet {

        /* Process the HTTP Post request */
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                response.setContentType("text/html"); 
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                // Obtain parameters from the client
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String passwd = request.getParameter("passwd");

                if (Interpreter.usernameExists(username)) {
                        out.println("<br><br>That username already exists.<br>");
                        response.setStatus(417);
                }
                else if (!passwd.equals(request.getParameter("passwd1"))) {
                        out.println("<br><br>Please confirm password<br>");
                        response.setStatus(409);
                }
                else {
                        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
                        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
                        String status = request.getParameter("status");
                        Student CreateStudent = new Student(username, passwd, firstName, lastName, status);
                        Interpreter.saveStudentCredentials(CreateStudent);
                        
                        out.println("<br><br>Account created successfully<br>");
                        response.setStatus(200);
                }
                out.close(); // Close stream
        }
}
```

Any help please? it's my 1st front end school project. It's been long debugging this error with no success.

I was expecting a createAccount page with result of the doPost() printed out.
[click here to view my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0G91.png)

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form, only input fields with the name attribute are submitted.
For inputs '***username***', '***new-password***' and '***new-password1***', there is no name attribute and hence no data sent to server. So, accessing '***passwd***' variable (which is null) with equals method will throw '***NullPointerException***'.

Comment: Thanks bsk_srikrishnan. I changed code to reflect your suggestion I still get the same result. I did the below modifications to debug and it looks like the servlet receives the request headers and data but responds with 405, undefined method. I still can't find that undefined method. It was just a post request with a one line text response message. I updated the code above to reflect the changes if you care to have a look please.